# Firefox addon: How to insert an iFrame on page load based on current domain name

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to add an iframe into body of current document before the first child with Firefox Addon.

What I am doing:

- Addon read the current URL domain name
- Send domain name to personal server
- server Then Insert iframe into body populated with respective content

I read all possible Mozilla documents but I wouldn't find any thing that's stating about inserting HTML elements into the current webpage. I am new with Firefox Development.

To read domain name:

```
var domain = document.domain; //not working
```

I tried following code to insert iframe:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
 var ifrm =document.createElement('<iframe src=http://www.example.com/addon></iframe>');
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.org",
  contentScript: 'document.body.insertBefore(ifrm, document.body.firstChild);'
});
```

Problem:

- Is it possible with Firefox addon, or I should switch to Firefox extension
- How to insert iframe into body

Comment: This may not be a complete solution to your problem, but you are doing a createElement in the wrong way. Try something like `var ifrm =document.createElement('iframe');
    ifrm.setAttribute('src','http://www.example.com/addon');
    document.body.insertBefore(ifrm, document.body.firstChild);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the code you posted belongs to your lib/main.js file which does not has access to any DOM content. That's why in you have no **document** object so you can't access neither **document.domain** nor **document.createElement**. In order to access DOM content you need to use a [Content Script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Accessing_the_DOM) , in your case, using the script associated with the PageMod this way:

**lib/main.js**:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.org",
  when: "ready",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("script.js") 
});
```

**data/script.js**:

```
var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://example.com/addon");
document.body.insertBefore(ifrm, document.body.firstChild);
```

Comment: I've been using the addon sdk for a while but just recent I had the need to inject an iframe but, even though I'm using a code very simillar to this one, the iframe just refuses to render. It does inject into the page but it just display nothing: no message, no console error or warning, just emptiness.
Any ideas?

Comment: @AlbertoAlexanderRodriguez Might be caused by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy, i.e., if the urls of the injected iframe and the original page differ (and the original page responds with x-frame-options:"SAMEORIGIN")